# High/low game in python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

'''

```
import random

correct_num = random.randint(0,10)

guess = int(input('What is your guess?'))
while guess != correct_num:
    if guess > correct_num:
        print('Your guess is to big')
    if guess < correct_num:
        print('Your guess is to small')
    else:
        if guess == correct_num:
            print('Yes! You are correct')
```

'''

This is what I have so far, when I run the code it prints the output infinitely. How can I make it give one output and go back for another guess?

Comment: Start with `guess = -1`, so that the while loop always runs at least once, and put the `guess = int(input(...))` _inside_ the while loop instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can simply do this:**

```py
import random

correct_num = random.randint(0,10)


while True:
    guess = int(input('What is your guess?'))
    if guess == correct_num:
        print('Yes! You are correct')
        break
    elif guess > correct_num:
        print('Your guess is to big')
    elif guess < correct_num:
        print('Your guess is to small')
```

Comment: Do ```if...elif...elif``` instead of 3 separate blocks of ```if```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take input inside the loop. Also, you can set `guess=-1` because the random number will never be -1 because it doesn't lie in the range.

```
import random
guess=-1
correct_num = random.randint(0,10)
while guess != correct_num:
    guess = int(input('What is your guess?'))
    if guess > correct_num:
        print('Your guess is to big')
    if guess < correct_num:
        print('Your guess is to small')
    else:
        if guess == correct_num:
            print('Yes! You are correct')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the keyword break at the end of your if statement and your problem is solved. By the way you can also try giving the user say like 3 attempts also. In our case its 1 attempt only.

```py
import random

correct_num = random.randint(0,10)

guess = int(input('What is your guess?'))

while guess != correct_num:

    if guess > correct_num:
        print('Your guess is to big')
        break
    elif guess < correct_num:
        print('Your guess is to small')
        break
    else:
        if guess == correct_num:
            print('Yes! You are correct')
            break
```